# ImportError: cannot import name 'parallel_helper'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip, anaconda, amazon-sagemaker

whenever I'm running - `from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier`

I'm getting an error - `ImportError: cannot import name 'parallel_helper'`
the stack trace is -

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-d80da5c856d8> in <module>()
      1 # feature removal using ROC-AUC score
----> 2 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
      3 roc_values = []
      4 for feature in diabetes_MICE_X.columns:
      5     clf = RandomForestClassifier()

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/__init__.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 from .base import BaseEnsemble
----> 7 from .forest import RandomForestClassifier
      8 from .forest import RandomForestRegressor
      9 from .forest import RandomTreesEmbedding

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py in <module>()
     59 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning, NotFittedError
     60 from .base import BaseEnsemble, _partition_estimators
---> 61 from ..utils.fixes import parallel_helper, _joblib_parallel_args
     62 from ..utils.multiclass import check_classification_targets
     63 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted

ImportError: cannot import name 'parallel_helper'


Note - I'm using jupyter notebook (conda_python3) in sagemaker.
scipy version = 1.3.1
numpy version = 1.17.2
scikit version = 0.21.3 


one strange thing that i'm unable to figure out is - whenever i do 

import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

its gives me output as 0.22

can someone help me on this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to overcome this problem in sagemaker is to use lifecycle configuration.
Rather than doing pip install inside the notebook, write all your requirements.txt installs inside the lifecycle configurations. The notebook will take more time to spawn but the code but the libraries will be pre-installed.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to restart the kernel. I had a similar experience on google colab, restarting the runtime solved the problem.